# json_replace() to update int + 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where I am storing some json using the json field type and one of the values being stored is `{'views':1}` ... basically just a view counter for the object.

I have tried *(guessing, to be honest)* a few different methods to get the int to update, but not having any luck.

I know with a standard int field it is just a matter of `SET views = views + 1` but not exactly getting the right method for using `json_replace()`.

I really would prefer to not have to do a `select -> json_decode -> update the views number -> json_encode -> update`, but if that is the only option we got at this point, so be it, but figured I would ask before going with that method.

I am running mysql 5.7.25

Thanks

Comment: Have you try the mysql JSON_SET,  [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-paths)?

Comment: @abn - nope. figured they were both pretty much the same for this kind of an update. Still leads me to not being sure how the `value+1` syntax is suppose to work though.